# Compare all row values agains list and count matches

Tags: pandas

I want to count the occurrence of a list of integers in a pandas dataframe. All columns of the dataframe should be compared against the list.

E.g.
I have a list of unique numbers

```
>>> numbers
[15, 23, 30, 21, 2, 20]
```

I have a dataframe

```
>>> df
   n1  n2   n3   n4   n5   n6   n7
0   1  13   14   32   34   44    7
1   7  11   23   28   29   30   19
2   2  19   28   29   33   42   15
...
```

Now I want the ocurrence of the numbers in the list, in any of the columns.

```
>>> df.some_function(numbers)
   n1  n2   n3   n4   n5   n6   n7   occurrence
0   1  13   14   32   34   44    7   0
1   7  11   23   28   29   30   19   2
2   2  19   28   29   33   42   15   1
...
```

I know I could just iterate the rows, but I am looking for a cheaper way to do this if it's possible.

Thanks

Comment: why do you expect 2 in the second row for occurence?

Comment: Unfortunately there are some different numbers in both DataFrames, for columns `n3, n6`

Comment: Sorry, I modified the data to make it more clear. I messed it up a bit. It's fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare values by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and then count `True`s by `sum`:

```
numbers = [15, 23, 30, 21, 2, 20]
df['occurrence'] = df.isin(numbers).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  n7  occurrence
0   1  13  14  32  34  44   7           0
1   7  11  23  28  29  30  19           3
2   2  19  28  29  33  42  15           2
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!